# How to get all tax rates from Magento2 through rest api?

Tags: php, rest, magento-2.0

I want to fetch all tax rates from magento2, i tried 
http://magento2url/rest/default/V1/taxRates/2", here it gives tax rate information of perticular id but i want all.

I tried the following url:
http://magento2url/index.php/rest/V1/taxRates?searchCriteria[currentPage]

here response is :

stdClass Object
(
    [message] => Request does not match any route.
)

the same url, if i give products 
http://magento2url/index.php/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria[currentPage] is working fine.

Please suggest if any one know the answer or give any suggestion how can i proceed here ?

Answer (score 2):

Please try this end point 
**"/V1/taxRates/search?searchCriteria",**
if you want specific field you can use 
**"/V1/taxRates/search?searchCriteria&fields=items[tax_country_id,tax_region_id,region_name,rate]"**

Answer (score 0):

give the url as follows to get all tax rates

http://magentourl/index.php/rest/V1/taxRates/search?searchCriteria[currentPage]

this same for customers also.just rename taxRates to customers to get all customers of current page.